# Request in PUT mode for python with xls file as data in Requests

Tags: python, api, python-requests, put, xls

I am trying to use requests with PUT mode in Python in order to import an xls file with a whitelist to a camera. My file is on my desktop.

I have tested the API in postman and asked postman to export my API in python. My command in postman with digest authorization enabled is presented bellow.

```
http://admin:*******@192.168.88.243/ISAPI/Traffic/channels/1/licensePlateAuditData
```

I have tried it in my Python request test like presented bellow and works with report 200OK

```
PUT http://admin:*******@192.168.200.108/ISAPI/Traffic/channels/1/licensePlateAuditData
Content-Type: text/plain
```

I have used postman to translate my API in Curl and Python Request and the results are presented below.

### Python Request

```
import requests

url = "http://192.168.88.243/ISAPI/Traffic/channels/1/licensePlateAuditData"

payload = "<file contents here>"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
}
```

---

### Curl

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://192.168.88.243/ISAPI/Traffic/channels/1/licensePlateAuditData' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-binary '@/C:/Users/gerki/Desktop/me=teNolist_192.168.88.243_20200407142606.xls'

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

---

I have started my code in Python to make it work by first making sure that my authorization works with a GET command first which you may see in a commented mode in my code below. The authorization worked fine.

### Python Code

```
ht4 = '/ISAPI/Traffic/channels/1/licensePlateAuditData'
ht1 = 'http://192.168.200.108'
ht3 = 'http://192.168.200.109'
ht = ht1 + ht4
htalt = ht3 + ht4

import requests

from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

for url in [ht, htalt]:
    try:
        from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

        payload = "C:/Users/gerki/Desktop/me=teNolist_192.168.88.243_20200407142606.xls"
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        }

        response = requests.request("PUT", url, data=payload, headers=headers, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('admin', 'OTE_2019'))

        # If the response was successful, no Exception will be raised
        response.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')  # Python 3.6
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')  # Python 3.6
    else:
        print('Success!')
        response.encoding = 'utf-8'
        print(response.text)
```

---

Then I get a 400 error which I suspect has to do with the way that python open the xls file.
My error code is

```
HTTP error occurred: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: http://192.168.200.108/ISAPI/Traffic/channels/1/licensePlateAuditData
```

Could someone explain if I may do the procedure somehow work? I need to apply the code in many IP addresses to apply the xls file in many cams. So I need code in python in order to create an executable and thus POSTMAN is not functional.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found what was wrong. Documentation was stating to use header inside the request. I just removed it and worked. I am attaching the code below.

> By the way, this answer is relevant to a very unique problem which is
>   based on how to create a small software to change the
>   Whitelist/blacklist of ***HIkvision*** Traffic/ANPR cameras. Up to now only
>   use of the camera GUI or PUT commands through POSTMAN or similar
>   systems could be used to do so.

So the answer is really helpful for many people out there who wish to use the **HIKVISION SDK for ANPR cameras**.

```
ht1 = '/ISAPI/ITC/capability'
ht2 = '/ISAPI/Traffic/channels/1/licensePlateAuditData'
ht3 = 'http://192.168.200.108'
ht4 = 'http://192.168.200.109'
htc = ht3 + ht2
htc2 = ht4 + ht2

import requests

from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

for url in [htc, htc2]:
    try:
        from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

        #response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('<username>', ',password>'))
        payload = open("<filename with full path>", 'rb')

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        }

        response = requests.put(url, data=payload, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('<username>', ',password>'))

        # If the response was successful, no Exception will be raised
        response.raise_for_status()
    except HTTPError as http_err:
        print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')  # Python 3.6
    except Exception as err:
        print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')  # Python 3.6
    else:
        print('Success!')
        response.encoding = 'utf-8'
        print(response.text)
```